# Android back stack one fragment, when pressing hardware back button shows the back stacked one.

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

Android back stack one fragment, when pressing hardware back button shows the back stacked one.

Below is my expected scenario:

I have one activity with navigation drawer. Each navigation element navigate to different fragments on click. I want to back stack only the home fragment. when pressing back button from any other fragments , navigate to the home fragment. When pressing the back button from home fragment, app exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle **onBackPressed** method in this method, comment the line `//super.onBackPressed();`

```
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
//            super.onBackPressed();
//Now check if current fragment is not home fragment
// then replace current fragment with home fragment
//if current fragment is home fragment then execute the following code
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
    startActivity(homeIntent); 

        }
```